# Force the user to be on specific tab and detects when he tries to switch tabs

Tags: android

I am using tabs with tabhost. I have 4 tabs and I want the user to be only to view the content of the first tab. If he clicks on any other tab, then I should display msg and return back to the first tag.
How can I achieve that?

I tried doing that by creating  onTabChanged listener and inside this method I would do

```
if( th.getCurrentTab()!=0){
    th.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
    alert("my msg");
    return;
}
```

But the problem that once  I return then the th.getCurrentTab is return 1 or 2 ( whatever the user clicked) and it seems its not working.
any other ideas or way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Id of the tab you want to keep the user sticked to is fixed and is the first one, you don't need to perform the `if( th.getCurrentTab()!=0) {` check, simply use the `setCurrentTab` statement. You don't need to check on which tab the user is as you know that you just want them to be on the first one. And it won't start an infinite loop because clicking or setting the current tab to the same tab won't trigger the `onTabChanged` event.

Using something like this should work as you expect:

```
public void onTabChanged(final String tabId) {
  th.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
  alert("my msg");
  return;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when the user clicks on tab 2. and the above code executes something is out of sync. Because by the end of the code, th.getTabWiget.getCurrentTab is returning 2 not 0!

Comment: I found the answer. I posted it below

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Apperently  I should be using th.setCurrentTab(0) not th.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0)